# $_SESSION not saving in database

Tags: mysql, forms, session

Ok, I have a site that users have to log in to in order to submit a form, a character sheet.  That form passes all the information to a page for inserting into a database.  The very first thing on both the form page and the action page is

```
<?php
session_cache_expire(360);
session_start();
?>
```

Also on the form is a place where the $_SESSION['logname'] is echoed so you can see the user's name on the page:

```
<p>Logged in as:<br />
<?=$_SESSION['logname']?>
```

That is working, it correctly shows the person logged in.  Now, on the page set in the action of the form, the code is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (\"$_SESSION[logname]\",\"$_POST[char_name]\",NOW())";
```

I have checked the fields in the database many times, and they are correct, however, the $_SESSION[logname] is not saving to the database, when looking at it via phpMyAdmin, the field is just blank.  So the information for the $_SESSION[logname] is not making it from echoing on the form to being entered into the database. I have tried ['logname'] and [logname] and neither work.

I have also tried to add

```
<input type="hidden" name="log_name" value="<? $_SESSION['logname'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="owner" value="<? $_SESSION['logname'] ?>" />
```

to the form, as well as

```
<td>Player Name:</td>
<td><? echo $_SESSION['logname'] ?></td>
```

and changed the INSERT to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (\"$_POST[logname]\",\"$_POST[char_name]\",NOW())";
```

When viewing the form to fill it in, the Player Name is echoing the correct session information and it still isn't saving...

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the session login to save in the player name field?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Before going any further, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Then, what code is executing the sql and are there any errors reported. $_POST[logname] and $_POST[char_name] would not work because those are not the names of the input parameters (log_name, owner). Have you tried hardcoding insert values to verify the db insert?

Comment: The input parameters are correct.  the database fields are log_name and char_name, the session parameter is logname and the form field is owner...

Comment: clearly stated in original question " I have tried ['logname'] and [logname] and neither work." 

@JRD the rest of the form saves to the database, just not the $_SESSION[logname].  .....

As I understand sql, the statements are built as "INSERT INTO tablename (table fields) VALUES ($_POST[form input field]);" so I have made sure, several times, that the table fields match what is in the table and the form fields match what is on the form and that they are paired properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you are missing some single quotations there with your variables:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (\"$_POST['logname']\",\"$_POST['char_name']\",NOW())";
```

or you could simply use local variables:

```
$logname = $_SESSION['logname'];
$char_name = $_SESSION['char_name'];
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (".$logname.", ".$char_name." ,NOW())";
```

Comment: YES!!!  Adding $logname=$_SESSION['logname']; and then changing the $_SESSION[logname] to $logname worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: My apologies... new to stackoverflow ... will remember for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing single quotation in query   `' '`
 your code is

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (\"$_SESSION[logname]\",\"$_POST[char_name]\",NOW())";
```

i think you should use single quotation in `$_SESSION['logname']` and `$_POST['char_name']`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES (\"$_SESSION['logname']\",\"$_POST['char_name']\",NOW())";
```

Comment: If it were a matter of the ' around the names within the [ ], then none of the fields would save, correct?  So then it can't be that, because the rest of the information from the form is saving, just NOT the $_SESSION[logname] ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES ('{$_SESSION['logname']}', '{$_POST['char_name']}' ,NOW())";
```

If it does not works then, write `echo mysql_error();` after your mysql_query($sql) statement. `echo mysql_error();` will print out actual error in your query. It will give you a clear idea about why the insert query is not executing properly.

Comment: I do have it echoing:

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("<p>Couldn't add character.<br/>".mysql_error().);

And no error shows... it's just flat not saving the $_SESSION['logname'] ...

Comment: try echoing the query like `echo $sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_name,create_date) 
VALUES ('{$_SESSION['logname']}', '{$_POST['char_name']}' ,NOW())";` and when the query is printed then copy the query and execute it from phpmyadmin does it inserts the data from phpmyadmin